# Is it possible to find out the smallest size of a C union

Tags: c, sizeof, unions

The size of a C union(sizeof()) is the size of its largest element.

However, is there any trick to find out what might be the smallest size of the union programmably?

I meant something along the line of how offsetof MACRO is implemented...

Comment: The size of a union does not vary with the member that currently holds a value.  It is always large enough to hold the largest member, and it can be larger.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure your opening statement is necessarily true. Perhaps an expert can confirm?

Comment: @Bathsheba; That's how memory is allocated for unions.

Comment: @haccks Re "The size of a C union(sizeof()) is the size of its largest element": Strictly speaking, the size will be *larger* for odd max element sizes without pack instructions to the compiler. Oh, John said that already, I see now...

Comment: @Bathsheba Memory size for a union is/can be determined before any value is assigned to it.  The size of a variable does not change during its lifetime.  Even VLAs do not change size _during_ its lifetime.

Comment: *"The size of a C union(sizeof()) is **at least** the size of its largest element, **and frequently larger.**"*  (fixed it for you)

Comment: A _compound literal_ approach could use the well defined C99 `sizeof (some_type){0}.element1` for an element's size.  Not certain putting this in a macro adds clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the size of the smallest member of a union type without declaring a variable of that type, and without referring to the type of the member. The following trick to get the size of a member will probably work, but is a little on the dodgy side:

```
#define membersize(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member)
```

You'll have to compute the size of each member individually to determine which is the smallest, so if someone adds a new member to the union, you'll have to alter the code that determines the smallest member size to account for it.

Comment: I don' t get this, if you already know the type why not simply use `sizeof(type)`?

Comment: No it is not a good trick. `MYSTERIOUS_MACRO(struct_type, member_name)` is much worse than `sizeof( ((struct_type*)0)->member_name)`. Please don't try to re-invent the C language and replace it with some mysterious macro language.

Comment: @Lundin, but in this way you get the `sizeof` a pointer not the size of the type, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann Edited the comment. Either method is mostly nonsense anyway. Maybe a compound literal would be slightly less ugly.

Comment: @Lundin, OP wanted something "something along the line of how offsetof MACRO is implemented", so I used a macro.

Comment: @Ian. Is the "type" referring to the union type? If so, this is very similar to the trick to find out the size of a struct member.

Comment: The intermediate cast to `(void *)` is redundant, so I edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: I also changed the name of the macro from `elemsize` to `membersize`, as that is more appropriate.

Comment: Hmmm A `void*` can be cast to an arbitrary pointer type.  Code now casts an integer to an arbitrary pointer type - not sure that would pass a language-lawyer review.  Will have to research that sometime.

Comment: I am not sure this is useful. In order to know the member name you usually must know the union's declaration, meaning you have the member type -- and hence its size -- anyway, without any ado.

Comment: @chux I did check first before removing the intermediate `void*` cast, just to make sure it was okay. **6.3.2.2 Pointers** 3 An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a _null pointer constant_. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a _null pointer_, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that looks good enough for me too.  (Found it with a different number in the current C spec: C11dr 6.3.2.3 Pointers 3)

Comment: @chux Yes, that was a typo, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 ways to answer this question:

1. Each union has only one size, so that would be the smallest size of it as well.
2. If what you *really* wanted was the smallest size of the elements that make up the union, then compute the size of each element in isolation and take the minimum of those.

Answer (score 2):

Only as an exercise:

1. using a specific pattern for your union members
2. taking care of update the code each time you update the union
   members
3. Using a variable to trace the end of each member

you can do something like below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

struct s1
{
    uint8_t member;
    uint8_t len;
};

struct s2
{
    uint16_t member;
    uint8_t len;
};

struct s3
{
    uint32_t member;
    uint8_t len;
};

typedef union u1
{
    struct s1 m1;
    struct s2 m2;
    struct s3 m3;
}UNION_TEST;

#define RETRIEVE_MEMBER(memberNum) m##memberNum
#define test(unionName, memberName) offsetof(unionName, memberName.len)+sizeof(uint8_t)

int main(void)
{
   printf("sizeof = %zu\n", test(UNION_TEST, RETRIEVE_MEMBER(1)));
   printf("sizeof = %zu\n", test(UNION_TEST, RETRIEVE_MEMBER(2)));
   printf("sizeof = %zu\n", test(UNION_TEST, RETRIEVE_MEMBER(3)));
}
```

Comment: You are killing flies with a bazooka :) ... a waste of space if those structs are used in arrays

Comment: @AlterMann :D. As I wrote: I did it as exercise.

Comment: I know, it's a joke :D

Comment: @chux is offsetof return value size_t?

Comment: @chux Thx. Edited.